# Compton Scattering conservation of energy derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

For Special Relativity, conservation of energy has the following equation:

$$KE = (\gamma_u -1)mc^2,$$

where $\gamma_u$ is Lorentz factor, which I understand the derivation.

Now considering Compton scattering, I noticed the following equation being used:

$$KE = (\gamma_u -1)mc^2 = \frac{hc}{\lambda} - \frac{hc}{\lambda'},$$

but I am not sure how that was derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy of a photon is $h\nu$ or $hc/\lambda$, so the right side is the energy loss of the photon and the left side is the energy gain of the electron. This is in a reference frame where the electron is at rest before interacting with the photon.

Comment: Yes, that part I understand but what is the relationship $$(\gamma_u -1)mc^2 = \frac{hc}{\lambda} - \frac{hc}{\lambda'}$$ since the equation on the right has no reference to mass nor Lorentz factor.

Comment: Photons don’t have any mass and don’t have a Lorentz factor since they travel at the speed of light. (Or, if you want to say they do, it’s infinite.)

Comment: So you cannot express the energy of a photon in terms of its mass and speed. You *can* express its energy in terms of its frequency, its wavelength, or its momentum. Here, it is in terms of wavelength.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for the clarification!